# getting error during make in ubuntu for procmon

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, kernel

```
$ make 
gcc -Wall -D__KERNEL__ -DLINUX -DMODULE -O -I /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include/   -c -o procmon.o procmon.c
In file included from /lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/build/include/linux/kernel.h:13:0,
                 from procmon.c:22:
/lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/build/include/linux/linkage.h:5:25: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [procmon.o] Error 1
```

Im trying to compile using the make file of procmon system analysis module. I got the above message can any one help me out what is the problem?

Comment: check you have kernel sources or at least kernel headers installed. You can do it with apt-get

Comment: it was problem with kernel version. the kernel headers are already there.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your makefile like this:

obj-m :=procmon.o

all:

```
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

install: all

```
    rm -rf /dev/procmon
    mknod /dev/procmon c 240 1
    chmod 400 /dev/procmon
```

clean:

```
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *~
    rm -f a.out
    rm -f test*
    rm -f DEADJOE
```

dist: clean

```
    cd .. ; tar cvzf procmon.tar.gz procmon
```

If you get any errors like devfs related, your procmon code will not work on recent kernels, you need to change the code accordingly

Comment: $ make
Makefile:9: *** missing separator.  Stop.
I got this error after changing the make file as told above..Can u help?

Comment: u still didn't get back to my query i still get an error as posted in my previous comment.